# what's the way to know if value is exists within an array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

what's the easiest way to find if a value exists within an array?

Example:

Let's say I have an `array = array('x','y','z')`
I want to return `True` if `'z'` (string) is present in the array else `False`

Answer (score 2):

Use ARRAY_CONTAINS which is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html

Comment: in order to use this I need to cast the string to a "variant", is this the only way?

Comment: What's the issue with doing that?

Comment: I would expect to have something more native to handle strings than casting to other types

Comment: Given that an array can contain any type(s) of objects, casting to VARIANT (which will work for any object type) seems to be the most flexible solution - otherwise Snowflake would need to create and maintain a version of this function for every possible data type e.g. ARRAY_CONTAINS_STRING, ARRAY_CONTAINS_NUMBER, ARRAY_CONTAINS_DATE, etc.